# How do I rewrite an id to a name via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the title ID through htaccess but it does not work. I used several different codes in htaccess but it does not work.
When I went to the url by name it did not show me any post, but with ID it works very well.

I am using this code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z]+)/?$ news-details.php?nid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

ID for posts/categories:

```
127.0.0.1/new/news-details.php?nid=89
127.0.0.1/new/category.php?catid=9
```

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file located? What is the actual URL(s) you are requesting? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite .hraccess located in: localhost/new/ i have nothing in htaccess except rewrite code.

Comment: I'm looking for the url of the title that is associated with the ID
Example I have an id = 30 and "PostUrl" is in the table in db.
I want to see an article via PostUrl not ID

Comment: Sorry, can you please include an example of the actual URL you are requesting? It sounds like you are wanting to pass the "title"? But that is not going to be possible if the target URL is expecting an "id". (?) You would need to include the "id" somewhere in the requested URL.

Comment: The directive you included in the question would rewrite a request for `/new/89` to `/new/news-detail.php?nid=89`. "i have nothing in htaccess except rewrite code" - I'm assuming you have `RewriteEngine On`? But nothing else?

Comment: I will tell you more simply, I want to rewrite the URL "news-details.php?nid=89" and add "url" as href localhost/new/89/url
url works like this: news-details.php?nid=89/name-news
and I want to remove it via rewrite "news-details.php?nid=89" and leave only /name-news example name-news.html or I know will add it to rewrite.

Comment: Yes it works through the id "/new/89" you mentioned but not with url "/new/89/name-news"

Comment: Or if it is possible to be id "89" and name "/new/89/name-news how can this be done through rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Yes it works through the id "/new/89" you mentioned but not with url "/new/89/name-news"
> ```

Then change the rule (the regex) to allow `/<id>/<slug>` (no trailing slash), for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+/[\w-]+)$ news-details.php?nid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

`<id>/<slug>` is then past as the value of the `nid` URL parameter.

Comment: It seems to work, but it loses the style/img of the site:
GET http://127.0.0.1/new/89/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
ttt:31 GET http://127.0.0.1/new/89/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Root You need to make sure you are using root-relative (or absolute) URLs to your static resources. See my answer to the following question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: Yes dear i fix it, thank you, you helped me a lot! But with the category must use the same code it differs from "nid=" "catid="

Comment: @Root Yes, you would need to use a "similar" rule for the other URL. However, you would need a slightly different URL format in order to avoid a conflict.

Comment: Thanks dear, I will try it for menu-id but now I have a problem with url 
$arr = explode(" ",$posttitle); and $url = implode ("-", $ arr); she is getting characters in url and news is coming out 404.

Comment: You'll need to either restrict the regex based on the URLs you are expecting or parse the URL in PHP (or both).

Comment: Thank dear! I check for this, it is possible that this can be done from the mysql table not to accept characters in url